# UITableViewCells scroll over header when scrolling down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to figure out what my options are for having the top of a UITableView be able to stay at rest about 1/3 down the screen but still be able to scroll over the top of an image above it.

I was thinking UITableView on a UIScrollView but I haven't seen this exact thing while googling around for it.

Basically I'm looking to have a header and then the table view will scroll over the top of the header without the header moving. If I set the table view below a simple uiview or imageview, it will always be below it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your header as a separate view below your table view. Your table view should completely overlap the underlying view, as if it would obscure it. Then set the table view's `tableHeaderView` to a transparent UIView, through which you will be able to see your underlying header view. Your table view's background colour should also be clear.

```
CGRect headerFrame = self.underlyingHeaderView.bounds;
UIView *transparentView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
transparentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = transparentView;
```